# "StackExchangeLogin" — if I don't see this button, I can't log in!

Tags: support, login

Oftentimes, esp. out of a cafe, I see that the log in page of any SE site loads fine up to the point where the buttons 'Log in with Stack Exchange' / Google / Yahoo ... are supposed to show up.

I only see an ellipsis suggesting the images are loading, but this '...' gif stays indefinitely. The buttons never appear.

Q: **In such a case, do I have an alternate way to log in?**

I would want to log in only with the 'Log in with Stack Exchange' option.

I don't know if this is due to some Java issues with a particular machine at the cafe. However, I can neither move to another terminal nor change settings majorly on this terminal.

**Edit:** I still haven't found a workable solution for this. Any other thoughts?

Comment: How is that could be a *java* problem?

Comment: @om-nom-nom: Well, it's obvious, it takes forever to load. ;) SCNR

Comment: If not java then is that a javascript problem? More confusion ahead or what?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd I got *A problem occurred with this request*.There is *auth code* embedded in url, so this will not work.

Comment: @om-nom-nom Can you please restore your answer?

Comment: @om-nom-nom ok, it was far fetched anyway - removed. :/

Comment: @om-nom-nom as for your answer, it should be possible to execute JS code on the fly from Console in any modern web browser even IE9 and it actually worked for me. So +1 once you will undelete it.

Comment: @Kris yep, I've restored

Answer (score 2):

**Not** sure but you can try to type this into your browser address bar and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image]

(In example I've used google as an OpenID provider, but there is also `stack_exchange`, `yahoo`, `myopenid` and `facebook`)

Comment: Thanks. Does that, btw, require "javascript enabled" setting or something? Again, I am not quite into these things really.

Comment: 1) Firefox already dropped support for the `javascript:` protocol for security reasons, and I think the trend is towards other browsers doing the same. If you want to run JavaScript, use the browser console instead. 2) If the JavaScript that does the OpenID magic did not load, then this won't work. If it *did* work, it's quite unlikely you would not be able to see the buttons

Comment: @YiJiang'sProble_ yeah, thanx for clarifying, I had a huge doubt about how this would work if javascript stuck in some place on the page.